# Semiconductors out of equilibrium

Tags: mosfet, current, semiconductors, pn-junction, fermi

In connecting two separated materials with different Fermi levels we have carrier flow. Do electrons and holes always move in opposite directions?

Comment: What does an electron leave behind when it moves?

Comment: When an electron moves, it leaves behind a hole

Comment: @AlessandraRicci when an electron in the valence band moves it leaves behind a hole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply a voltage to an intrinsic semiconductor electrons and holes always move in the opposite direction. Electrons and holes always move in opposite directions because holes are not real charge carriers they are vacant places inside the crystal lattice created by the motion of electrons in the valence band.